# I am performing wordcount in Mapreduce and getting the following error in -copyToLocal

Tags: hadoop

```
hduser@hduser:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /output1
```

this is my command executed
    Found 2 items
    -rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup          0 2015-04-20 10:40 /output1/_SUCCESS
    -rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup          0 2015-04-20 10:40 /output1/part-r-00000

But i have already a part-r-00000 present in my hduser, so it is giving the following error.Is there any method that i can see my word count without coping to local

```
hduser@hduser:~$ hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /output1/part-r-00000 .copyToLocal: `part-r-00000': File exists
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> hduser@hduser:~$ **hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /output1/part-r-00000** .copyToLocal: `part-r-00000': File exists

The syntax for copyToLocal is `hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /hdfs/file/to/be/copied /local/filesystem/path`

Try this in terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/new
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/new
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /output1/part-r-00000 /usr/new/part-r-00000
```

> hduser@hduser:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /output1
>   Found 2 items -rw-r--r-- 1 hduser supergroup 0 2015-04-20 10:40 /output1/_SUCCESS -rw-r--r-- 1 hduser supergroup **0** 2015-04-20 10:40 /output1/part-r-00000

In `-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser supergroup 0 2015-04-20 10:40 /output1/part-r-00000`, the value `0` denotes that the file `part-r-00000` is empty. When you copy an empty file from HDFS, you will only get an empty file in local filesystem.

Comment: I tried thid command but /usr/new/part-r-00000 is empty. There is nothing copied there

Comment: Can you view the file content by browsing the HDFS filesystem in Namenode web interface found in `http://localhost:50070`?

Comment: Your hdfs file size is shown as `0` which means its empty. Thats why you get empty file when you copy it to local filesystem.

Comment: Thank you so much. now i am getting the right answer. Thank you

Comment: Nice to hear it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The following instruction stores it in tmp directory of your system.

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /output1/part-r-00000 /tmp/
```